# Express-like routing for client-side Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, url-routing

I am writing some Javascript and I need to add a routing system, otherwise it would be tricky to manage as the list grows.

The Angular routing is good, but I don't want to add it as a dependency.  What are the options?

```
if(window.location.pathname==='/') {
  var $btn = $('<a />').html('btn').click(function() {
    $questionList.html(findAnswers());
  });
  $tabs.prepend($btn);
}

if(window.location.pathname==='/posts') {
  // some code will run when only on post page
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended writing a simple one as follows, it takes a regex string for path

```
/**
 * routing for client side code in express style
 */
var expressRouting = function() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var mapping = {};

  function get(url, callback) {
    mapping[url] = callback;
  };

  function listen() {
    Object.keys(mapping).forEach(function(key) {
      var regexp = new RegExp(key);
      if(regexp.test(path)) {
        var method = mapping[key];
        if(method) {
          method.call(this);
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    debug : mapping,
    path : path,
    get : get,
    listen : listen
  }
};

// usage

var myapp = expressRouting();

myapp.get('/$', function() {
  alert('Hey, only on the homepage')
});

myapp.get('/questions$', function() {
  alert('Hey, only on the questions page')
});

myapp.listen();
```

Answer (score 2):

[RouterJS](http://haithembelhaj.github.io/RouterJs/) and [HistoryJS](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) look like they might do what you're looking for.